# JavaScript setTimeout setInterval within one function

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, setinterval

I think I might be overtired but I cannot for the life of me make sense of this, and I think it's due to a lack of knowledge of javascript

```
var itv=function(){
 return setInterval(function(){
  sys.puts('interval');
 }, 1000);
}
var tout=function(itv){
 return setTimeout(function(){
  sys.puts('timeout');
  clearInterval(itv);
 }, 5500);
}
```

With these two functions I can call

```
a=tout(itv());
```

and get a looping timer to run for 5.5 seconds and then exit, essentially.

---

By my logic, this should work but it simply is not

```
var dotime=function(){
 return setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(function(){
   return setInterval(function(){
    sys.puts("interval");
   }, 1000);
  });
 }, 5500);
}
```

any insight in this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it cannot work because because your `setInterval` will be called AFTER the timeout! your original approach is correct and you can still wrap this into single function:

```
var dotime=function(){
  var iv = setInterval(function(){
    sys.puts("interval");
  }, 1000);
  return setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(iv);
  }, 5500);
};
```

Comment: This is definitely it.  He's not creating the interval until the timeout callback executes.

Comment: Thank you for the wake up call/concise answer, don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 4):

I think the mistake you're making is that the function `itv` doesn't return `setInterval(function(){ sys.puts('interval'); }, 1000)` it executes `setInterval(function(){ sys.puts('interval'); }, 1000)` and than returns back an ID that setInterval generates. That ID is then passed to the `clearInterval` function to stop what `setInterval(function(){ sys.puts('interval'); }, 1000)` is doing.

**Edit**: An example of one function that would work.

```
var dotime=function(){
 // Start our interval and save the id
 var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
  // This will get executed every interval
  sys.puts("interval");
 }, 1000);

 // Start our timout function
 setTimeout(function(){
  // This will get executed when the timeout happens
  clearInterval(intervalId); // Stop the interval from happening anymore
 }, 5500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to write your version, you see that you pass a function to clearInterval, where you should have passed it a timer id.

```
var dotime=function(){
 var g=function(){
  var f=function(){
   return setInterval(function(){
    sys.puts("interval");
   }, 1000);
  }
  clearInterval(f);
 }
 return setTimeout(g, 5500);
}
```

To make it work you shoud call the function :

```
  clearInterval(f());
```

Or, using your version :

```
var dotime=function(){
 return setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(function(){
   return setInterval(function(){
    sys.puts("interval");
   }, 1000);
  }());
 }, 5500);
}
```

Disclaimer : I didn't test this.